# Javascript - SetTimeout causes Browser to freeze

Tags: javascript

The problem I'm currently running into is the following:
I have a table containing of two rows. The first row contains the letters of a given word in alphabetical order. The second row is empty at the start. Every second, one letter from the first row shall be moved to the correct position. This works correctly for the first 5 letters, but then nothing happens anymore and after a short time, the browser freezes and I get a prompt, asking to stop the skript or to keep it running.
Here's my code

```
test.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src=".\test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div onclick="m_show_letter_example()">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="example_01" name="example_alphabet_01" type="text" value="A"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_02" name="example_alphabet_02" type="text" value="E"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_03" name="example_alphabet_03" type="text" value="E"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_04" name="example_alphabet_04" type="text" value="L"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_05" name="example_alphabet_05" type="text" value="M"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_06" name="example_alphabet_06" type="text" value="P"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_07" name="example_alphabet_07" type="text" value="S"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_08" name="example_alphabet_08" type="text" value="X"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="example_solution_02" name="example_solution_02" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_08" name="example_solution_08" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_01" name="example_solution_01" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_05" name="example_solution_05" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_06" name="example_solution_06" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_04" name="example_solution_04" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_03" name="example_solution_03" type="text"/></td>
            <td><input id="example_solution_07" name="example_solution_07" type="text"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

And the javascript file:

```
test.js

var timeout = null;

function m_show_letter_example()
{
  timeout = setTimeout(function()
  { 
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var unplaced_letters = [];
    for (var input_index = 0; input_index < inputs.length; ++input_index)
    {
        if (inputs[input_index].name.indexOf('example_alphabet_') == 0) {
            unplaced_letters.push(inputs[input_index]);
        }
    }
    var random_index = 0;
    var field = document.getElementsByName('example_alphabet_0' + random_index);
    while (document.getElementsByName('example_alphabet_0' + random_index).length == 0 )
    {
        random_index = Math.floor( (Math.random() * unplaced_letters.length) + 1);
    }

    var letter = document.getElementById('example_0' + random_index);
    var solution = document.getElementById('example_solution_0' + random_index);
    solution.value = letter.value;
    letter.value = "";
    letter.name = "used";

    m_show_letter_example();
  }, 1000);
}
```

I would be happy to hear any insights on why this is happening and how to solve this.
In case it matters, I have tested this in Firefox and Chrome.
Thanks in advance

Edit: added test.js

Comment: Where/what is test.js?

Comment: You obviously have a loop that may or may never stop. Show the JS

Comment: @Eric: thx, addded

Comment: Instead of picking a random number until you find one that hasn't been done yet, consider shuffling the array of valid numbers and then just iterating through that.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: thx for the idea. I used it and my problem disappeared. :) If anyone can still show me the error in my code above, I would still be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because of the random number selecting in while loop.
When there are 3 values this loop is going into infinite loop.

I have made few changes in script file and also add a data-index attribute to every example_alphabet_ input tag.

```
var timeout = null;

function m_show_letter_example()
{
  timeout = setTimeout(function()
 { 
    var unplaced_letters =  document.querySelectorAll("input[name^='example_alphabet_']");
    var unplaced_index = []
    for (var input_index = 0; input_index < unplaced_letters.length; ++input_index)
    {
        unplaced_index.push(unplaced_letters[input_index].getAttribute('data-index'));
    }
    var random_index = 0;
    var field = document.getElementsByName('example_alphabet_0' + random_index);
    while (document.getElementsByName('example_alphabet_0' + random_index).length == 0 )
    {
        random_index = unplaced_index[Math.floor( (Math.random() * unplaced_index.length))];
    }

    var letter = document.getElementById('example_0' + random_index);
    var solution = document.getElementById('example_solution_0' + random_index);
    solution.value = letter.value;
    letter.value = "";
    letter.name = "used";

    m_show_letter_example();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Hope this helps you in resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is right here:

```
while (document.getElementsByName('example_alphabet_0' + random_index).length == 0 )
{
    random_index = Math.floor( (Math.random() * unplaced_letters.length) + 1);
}
```

when this condition is true

```
document.getElementsByName('example_alphabet_0' + random_index).length == 0
```

and the length returned is always 0 the while loop will run indefinitely as there is no  condition to stop it. An unending while loop will always freeze your browser.